# Certain URLs don't go through PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up my nginx server with my PHP RESTful API. I have the following blocks in my `server{}` block:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/v1/* /v1/api.php last;
  rewrite ^/* /index.php last;
}

location * .*\.php$ {
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

However.. these seem not to be functioning properly. Basicly, I want every URL starting with `/v1/` to be rewritten to `/v1/api.php`, and anything else to `/index.php`.

This seems to be working partially. Sometimes it actually does go to `api.php`, but sometimes it just seems to download the file instead of processing it through PHP-FPM. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading a file means not being passed to the php engine, so I assume the problem is in that block definition
replace

```
location * .*\.php$ {
```

with

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

And probably it will work.